# using 'printf' to return string, not print it

Tags: php, string, printf

This may sound strange, but here goes.

I like using this technique of building a string in php

```
printf(__('This is %1$s, this is %2$s'), myFunction1(), myFunction2());
```

Obviously this directly prints the results whenever the function is called, but I would like to use this technique to just build a string, and then use it later elsewhere.

Is this possible?

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you visit the documentation page of a function in the PHP Manual you find always useful tips and related functions, for example [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to do this:

```
$var = sprintf(__('This is %1$s, this is %2$s'), myFunction1(), myFunction2());
```