# How to use strings with variables in codeigniter's language files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

for a localized website I want to create different language files.
But my main problem before starting the localiuation is, that i probably have strings with variables.

My theory is that i can use placeholders within my language files like:

```
$lang['somekey'] = "Hello Mr. %s, how are you?";
```

Is there a clean and nice way to parse those variables or do i have to develop a function for that?

Thanks.

Comment: check this one out: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Internationalization_and_the_Template_Parser_Class

Comment: It doesnt fix my problem - it is for non variable strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [codeigniter i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Internationalization-and-the-Template-Parser-Class) with PHP [.sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to achieve what you want. load up the codeigniter non-variable strings (with those format stuff), then pass it on to `.sprintf()` for formatting and assignment of values. it should replace the `%s` part.

it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600732/using-printf-to-return-string-not-print-it). [.sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) works like [.printf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), only that it returns the string rather than printing it.

Comment: Okay. Seems that CI doesn't have a built in solution for that. So i will build my own function to parse that with help of sprintf. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem and do it simply by using,

```
echo sprintf($this->lang->line('somekey'),'XYZ');//load language library before use
```

Read <kbd>[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)</kbd>

Comment: Isn't it an open door for XSS?

Comment: @SteeveDroz Only if you are brave enough to feed it with untrusted user input.

Comment: @f4der Great, now I feel dumb... and I don't even remember having commented that.